# nginx two wildcards in location rule

Tags: php, regex, nginx

I have this location rule in my config file and what I'm trying to do is to get two params from the `URL`.

I want to accept all characters including Latin, Cyrillic etc.

The problem is that `echo $_GET["video_name"];` returns both params like `first_param/second_param` and `echo $_GET["not"];` returns `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
location ~ ^/related/(.*)$/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/related.php?video_name=$1&not=$2;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx but why the 2 `$`s and two `$uri`? The `$` in regex should be the end of the expression.

Comment: as @chris85 was mentioning, two $ are the problem.

Comment: try `/related\/(.*?)\/(.*)$`

Comment: Post an example URL and also the expected converted url

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the first `$` is breaking the rule. It should be smth like this.

```
location ~ /related/(.*)/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/related.php?video_name=$1&not=$2;
}
```